# Lua: Changing a Date table to string or some other format

Tags: date, datetime, time, lua

I've looked around many pages that tell me about how date and time work in lua but haven't found a solution.
Basically I want to take the current date and time, then add 1 month to that date, and then save that new date to my MySQL table in a format that can I can later compare to the current day of that time. Like this: `if now > oldDate then do something`

I managed to get the current date/time as a table and add 1 month to it by doing this:

```
local t = os.date( "*t" )
t.month = t.month + 1
```

But I couldn't find out how to turn it back into some kind of DateTime format that I can store to MySQL and then compare.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lua's `os.date` accepts an optional time parameter as the second argument

```
> local t = os.date("*t")
> t.month = t.month + 1
> print(os.date("%Y-%m-%d", os.time(t)) 
2014-12-16
```

The string can then be inserted as a date into a MySQL table.

To compare two dates in Lua, compare the output of `os.time()`

```
if os.time() > os.time(t) then
    print("The time has come.")
end
```